# Facebook feed on iframe: How to deal with 'X-Frame-Options' set to 'DENY' error in Safari?

Tags: facebook, iframe, x-frame-options

Facebook feed: Refused to display in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'.

I am trying to display a facebook feed in an iframe on a website for a small business. It works fine on Chrome, but on Safari, I consistently get an error. The only solution that seems to make the error go away is to turn off "Prevent Cross Site Tracking" in Safari's settings. But this isn't reasonable for users to have to do this when the visit the site.

Anyone know of a solution for this error? Here is the code I am using for the iframe:

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/page.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fqualityhomerepairandimprovement&tabs=timeline&width=300&height=500&small_header=false&adapt_container_width=true&hide_cover=false&show_facepile=true&appId" width="300" height="500" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true" allow="autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; picture-in-picture; web-share"></iframe>
```